# CDC replication not working after few days of inactivity

Tags: debezium

I am struggling with a issue where Debezium is unable to continue CDC replication after a few days of inactivity on source DB (SQL Server Always ON). Debezium Version: 1.9.5
The Debezium is reading from a listener which is installed over the SQL server Always ON.

When i see the connector/task status - its seems RUNNING. But NO CDC data is transferred over the TOPICS.

I verified this by running a kafka console consumer and checking if any data is sent to the topics. I am using snapshot.mode=initial, which worked fine to do a FULL LOAD and continued with CDC for a couple of days, but stopped running without any errors.

Can someone please point me how to fix this. Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: Some firewalls will drop TCP connections after a period of inactivity.

Comment: Hi @snakecharmerb, Thank you for the reply.
Is there anyway i can prove it. I have been checking the logs but see nothing wrong in it.

What workaround would you suggest to tackle such problem?

Comment: I have a similar problem with Debezium. After the inital Snapshot, the changes are coming very slowly. In the beginning I thought that they were not coming in, but I noticed that that they do come in, but quite late. Did you manage to solve it ?